# How to read comboBox text when set as drop down list?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code that was working fine until I switched the `dropdownstyle` to `dropdownlist`.  Does anyone have any idea how I can rewrite the `comboBox1.Text != "None"` to work with the `SelectedItem` format?

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = "None";
    }

if (comboBox1.Text != "None")
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = true;
        }
```

Comment: When you hit that code in the debugger, what is the value of `Text`, and what do you think it should be? It works just fine for me.

Comment: There is no value for Text now that I've changed the style.  In a regular drop down, this will read the Text though.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the dropdownstyle, for either style the comboBox1.Text will return the selected item text as long as the selected item is present in comboBox1.Items.

Comment: The reason I ask is that the checkBox is checked even while the comboBox1.SelectedItem = "None" at form load.  And it is not checked if I switch the dropdownstyle back to dropdown rather than dropdownlist.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to have something in your combobox:

```
        comboBox1.Items.Add("None");
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = "None";
```

Once you do this, your if statement will work correctly.

Note that you can also add items to the combobox through the DataSource:

```
        var cList = new List<String>();
        cList.Add("One");
        cList.Add("None");

        comboBox1.DataSource = cList;
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = "None";

        if (comboBox1.Text != "None")
```

In this case, especially if you are binding a class object instead of a string, you will want to use the combobox's SelectedValue property instead of SelectedItem since SelectedItem will contain the actual class object.

Comment: Ok, I have filled the Items "Collection" in the Properties window for the comboBox, isn't that basically the same thing?

Comment: It's not exactly the same thing; when you use a DataSource, changes to the DataSource can be automatically picked up and shown in the combobox while changes to the Items collection have to be made manually. In addition, I don't believe that SelectedValue is populated unless you use DataSource.